# How to implement html seamless div scroll like on this mozilla page?

Tags: jquery, html, css, dreamweaver

I'm implementing a design similar to this
https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/partners/

As for the design I have no issues there. I have all the separate pages working. I just wasn't sure about how to implement the left nav div( which I now have done with the help of SO member pointing to scrollspy).

The last thing I need is how to implement that continuous page scrolling we see there... what plugin can I use to implement it on my page. The mozilla page's scrolling looks really cool, and please note I am not worried about how to implement that phone image that keeps falling through the pages. For now I just want the smooth scrolling to get going.

Update:

**Do I have to have one really long page with different colored sections** ? Is there a different way to implement the cool continous scrolling ?

Thank you :0

Comment: if you don't want a long page then there won't be any scrolling.

Comment: You would need to use css animation in order to create the fade. You may have to use Javascript `slideUp` to make the `<div>` that slides up.

Comment: Actually, I did realize that I could use a really long page , divide it in four sections and use spyscroll plugin to change it as it goes, the reason I ask here is that I want to be sure that a long page is the only way to do it and there is no other better way to implement it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you do need one long page, you could set overflow to hidden on your html which will hide the scrollbar and give a maybe better looking page. You could also add content using AJAX but I would not recommend this.